# input() function throwing error in presence of threading in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following code works as expected. It takes two inputs and outputs the same

```
import sys
import threading
def main():
    n = int(input("input n:"))
    parents = list(map(int, input("input parents:").split()))
    print("n is {0} and parents is {1}".format(n,str(parents)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The moment I add this additional code for enabling more depth for recursion and threading, it throws a value error. Inputs I give are '3' for the first input (without quotes) and '-1 0 1' for the second input (without quotes).

```
import sys
import threading
def main():
    n = int(input("input n:"))
    parents = list(map(int, input("input parents:").split()))
    print("n is {0} and parents is {1}".format(n,str(parents)))

sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7)  # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**27)   # new thread will get stack of such size
threading.Thread(target=main).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You have two instances of `main()` running, in two threads.  They're going to be fighting over the user's input; I would guess that one of them got the `3` (and is still waiting for more input), and the other one got the newline (thus returning an empty string from `input()`).

Answer (score 0):

The main() function is called from two places.

- First, From the **thread** main() function will be called

> ```
> threading.Thread(target=main).start()
> ```

- Second, the **__main__** will be called. So here also the main() function is called.

> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>         main()
> ```

- So you were asked to enter the "input n" two times. While entering the string value ('-1 0 1') the second time, you are giving value to the "input n" again. It's expecting int as input. So the issue is happening.

Code Fix:
Move the thread inside **main** and remove the existing main()

```
import sys

import threading


def main():
    n = int(input("input n:"))
    parents = list(map(int, input("input parents:").split()))
    print("n is {0} and parents is {1}".format(n, str(parents)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 7)  # max depth of recursion
    threading.stack_size(2 ** 27)  # new thread will get stack of such size
    threading.Thread(target=main).start()
```

I hope it'll help you...